# Calling a function in the active view's class from the app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code I have currently functions correctly, however, at present it throws a warning. As the app is to be shipped soon and this particular component is responsible for key functionality I figured it would be worth asking.

The code is as follows (modified slightly):

```
REC_AppAuthPage *thisView = ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;
[thisView receiveSomeString:someString];
```

'REC_AppAuthPage' is a UIViewController class.

The warning being thrown is:
"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'REC_AppAuthPage *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'"

My question is, is it okay to ignore the warning and release or does something need to be changed? If so what?

Cheers

Comment: The thing is you are assigning a UIViewcontroller pointer to your thisView object. But what is REC_AppAuthPage ? What is it derived from ? It would be better to fix the issue, so you better elaborate more hence we can figure out the problem.

Comment: REC_AppAuthPage is a UIViewController, I added this to the question.

Comment: Instead of **visibleViewController** try **topViewController** property. Hope that will do. Not sure though.

Comment: topViewController throws an error at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a specific cast to the assignment:

```
REC_AppAuthPage *thisView = (REC_AppAuthPage *)((UINavigationController*)self.window.
```

rootViewController).visibleViewController;